# Why isn't there a Power Book I?

Tags: television

I've seen adverts for *Power Book II: Ghost*. When I try to find *Power Book I*, there isn't one. When I [search "Power Book" on IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/find?q=Power%20Book&s=tt&ref_=fn_al_tt_mr), it mentions *II*, *III*, *IV*, and *V*, but not *I*.

Is there a reason there's no *Power Book I*?

Comment: The reason there's no *Power Book I* is that it appears to have been just called *Power*. https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3281796/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_2 I haven't watched any of it, one actor is continuity, so it may be a spin-off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At per Tetsujin's comment, the original series is actually just called *[Power](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3281796/?ref_=tt_sims_tt)*, and it aired between 2014 and 2020. The "Book II" in the title of *Power Book II* is equivalent to "Part 2". Why they chose to call the series "books" when they're actually TV series, I can't say, but that would be the source of your confusion.